# Help with "haggle/barter" feature on mobile application

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, mobile-application

[image]

**Overview**

I am working on a mobile app that has a feature which allows the buyer and seller of a good/service to debate the price and exact nature of a transaction. The process of this transaction (haggling) is fairly simple:

1) The user clicks on the haggle button. At the start of every transaction, the user has 3 haggle attempts.

2) The user selects their haggle price from a pre-determined range to promote fairness.

3) The user presses the send button and awaits response. In about 5-10 seconds, the user receives confirmation whether their haggle has been successful or not.

- If successful, the user can accept the haggle price and gets taken to the payment screen to confirm the transaction.
- If unsuccessful, the user can re-attempt to re-haggle. This process repeats itself until the user runs out of haggles, after which they can purchase more haggles.

**Problems currently faced**

I spent the afternoon mocking up the user flow for this but got stuck on a 3 things:

1) Each user has 3 haggle attempts at the beginning of the transaction. This is currently illustrated on the button before the user presses it i.e. **Haggle (3)** and on the second screen when they are about to send their haggle quote i.e. **Send (3)**. My concern is that that this may not be clear enough to first time users, is there anything I can do to make it *immediately obvious*?

2) Once the user clicks on the haggle button, they need to select the quote which they want to send. I am not comfortable with the layout of the UI elements in this modal window for two reasons.

- Firstly, I want to encourage users to click on the "get more haggles" button but only if they have 0 haggles. However, this means that the "get more haggles" button should only appear on certain conditions. How would I best model the user flow to accomplish the conditional display of this UI element?
- Secondly, I want it to be *immediately obvious* to users that they need to  decrease the price the price before clicking on the **send (3)** button. I thought the best way to do this would be to use a variant of the (+/-) button number incrementers. However, increasing a price is not synonymous with haggling, as you would always want to get a lower price. Are there any other design patterns I can follow to help me restructure this UI element?

3) How would I best communicate to the user whether their haggle has been successful or unsuccessful after they've sent their quote on the second screen in a non-obtrusive way. Should I get them to wait until they receive a response or switch back to the first screen and display it there?

- If I switch it back to the first screen, how would I get the user to focus on that item explicitly? Will it need to be done on a new page or on the search results screen?
- If I decide to freeze the app (with a loading button) or something, then how do I elegantly transition between the let's haggle setup to the haggle result setup?

Comment: How would you ensure that the user gets a "success/fail" haggle in 5-10 secs, wouldn't the seller have to accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.1 You seem to have space for a [ haggle (3 left) ] there. I believe that does it.

1.2 A "send haggle" button would be more clear. Don't use the counter inside the send button, though, inform that elsewhere. "You have 2 haggles left"

2.1 replace the "Send" button with a "get more haggles" paired with the above message changed to "You have 0 haggles left".

2.2 Suggest a starting haggle price and add (if needed) a message saying the user can change it.
 AND / OR flash the decrease button a couple of times.

3. Open up a modal communicating success/failure and give the user a option to navigate back to that item. ex.: "See item" or "try again!"